# Blank MDT 2013 boot screen on USB Deployment

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, mdt, usb-boot

I am attempting to do refreshes on some machines and on the bootup of a USB drive with a LiteTouch Image I get to the Microsoft Solutions Accelerators screen but I do not get a window for actions.

I burned the ISO file to the USB drive as an NFTS.

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: How long did you wait? Usually at this point MDT is trying to access the Server and in my experience times out after a while saying it cannot access the UNC path on the server. You can use F8 to start a command prompt. First thing to check is ipconfig. Do you have a NIC and IP address? There are also log files in c:\MININT\SMSOSD\OSDLOGS that may help.

Comment: Check that your computer has support for Windows 8/8.x Some computers do not have the driver capability. I try to stick to Windows 7 PE creations for compatibility. Windows 8 has essentially dropped support for older hardware. Windows 7 however still has support.

Comment: The machine had 8.1 installed which was installed via WDS on the same network so I assume drivers would be fine? I will try pulling up a command prompt and see if I can get the IP address.

Comment: Tell me how that worked